# Is there a more efficient way to do this? | Month conversion

Tags: java, performance

I was given a little task to complete where a user would be asked to input either a month or the numerical equivalent and it would return the numerical value of the entered month, or the month corresponding to the inputted numerical value. The constraints are as follows:
 - It must not contain a GUI of any kind
 - I have to use the BufferedReader for input
 - I have to use at least one Switch statement

If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.
My code so far is as follows:

```
/**
 * Month task
 * 
 * @author Dan Foad
 * @version 0.01
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Months {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        int iInput;
        boolean isParseable;
        String szInput;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please type either the number of the month, or the month itself to convert.");
        System.out.print("> ");
        szInput = br.readLine();

        try {
            Integer.valueOf(szInput);
            isParseable = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            isParseable = false;
        }

        if (isParseable) {
            iInput = Integer.valueOf(szInput);
            System.out.println(numberToMonth(iInput));
        }
        else {
            szInput = szInput.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(monthToNumber(szInput));
        }
        return;
    }

    public static String numberToMonth(int iMonth) {
        String MonthReturn;
        switch(iMonth) {
            case (1): MonthReturn = "January"; break;
            case (2): MonthReturn = "February"; break;
            case (3): MonthReturn = "March"; break;
            case (4): MonthReturn = "April"; break;
            case (5): MonthReturn = "May"; break;
            case (6): MonthReturn = "June"; break;
            case (7): MonthReturn = "July"; break;
            case (8): MonthReturn = "August"; break;
            case (9): MonthReturn = "September"; break;
            case (10): MonthReturn = "October"; break;
            case (11): MonthReturn = "November"; break;
            case (12): MonthReturn = "December"; break;
            default: MonthReturn = "0"; break;
        }
        return MonthReturn;
    }

    public static int monthToNumber(String szMonth) {
        int MonthReturn;
        switch(szMonth) {
            case ("january"): MonthReturn = 1; break;
            case ("february"): MonthReturn = 2; break;
            case ("march"): MonthReturn = 3; break;
            case ("april"): MonthReturn = 4; break;
            case ("may"): MonthReturn = 5; break;
            case ("june"): MonthReturn = 6; break;
            case ("july"): MonthReturn = 7; break;
            case ("august"): MonthReturn = 8; break;
            case ("september"): MonthReturn = 9; break;
            case ("october"): MonthReturn = 10; break;
            case ("november"): MonthReturn = 11; break;
            case ("december"): MonthReturn = 12; break;
            default: MonthReturn = 0; break;
        }
        return MonthReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have to use a switch statement then this is probably how they expected you to convert the months.

Comment: Is your code working? If not, what specific problems are you having?

Comment: My code works fine, I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to perform this, as currently it seems a bit odd to have two switch statements that basically perform the same function, albeit in reverse. Not sure how I would improve it though.

Comment: you can also take a look at `enum`

Comment: Heck, I'd just put the month names in a string array, then use the switch() to determine the direction of the conversion, just to bug the instructor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Calendar;
import static java.util.Calendar.APRIL;
import static java.util.Calendar.AUGUST;
import static java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER;
import static java.util.Calendar.FEBRUARY;
import static java.util.Calendar.JANUARY;
import static java.util.Calendar.JULY;
import static java.util.Calendar.JUNE;
import static java.util.Calendar.MARCH;
import static java.util.Calendar.MAY;
import static java.util.Calendar.NOVEMBER;
import static java.util.Calendar.OCTOBER;
import static java.util.Calendar.SEPTEMBER;

public class Months {
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
    Integer iInput = null;
    String szInput = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Please type either the number of the month, or the month itself to convert.");
    System.out.print("> ");
    szInput = br.readLine();

    boolean wasInt = false;
    try {
      iInput = Integer.valueOf(szInput);
      System.out.println(numberToMonth(iInput));
      wasInt = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }

    if (! wasInt) {
        szInput = szInput.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(monthToNumber(szInput));
    }
    return;
}

public static String numberToMonth(int iMonth) {
    switch(iMonth-1) {
        case (JANUARY): return "January"; 
        case (FEBRUARY): return "February"; 
        case (MARCH): return "March"; 
        case (APRIL): return "April"; 
        case (MAY): return "May"; 
        case (JUNE): return "June"; 
        case (JULY): return "July"; 
        case (AUGUST): return "August"; 
        case (SEPTEMBER): return "September"; 
        case (OCTOBER): return "October"; 
        case (NOVEMBER): return "November";
        case (DECEMBER): return "December";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}

public static int monthToNumber(String szMonth) {
  if (szMonth == null) {
    return 0;
  }
    switch(szMonth.toLowerCase()) {
        case ("january"): return 1 + JANUARY;
        case ("february"): return 1 + FEBRUARY;
        case ("march"): return 1 + MARCH;
        case ("april"): return 1 + APRIL;
        case ("may"): return 1 + MAY;
        case ("june"): return 1 + JUNE;
        case ("july"): return 1 + JULY;
        case ("august"): return 1 + AUGUST;
        case ("september"): return 1 + SEPTEMBER;
        case ("october"): return 1 + OCTOBER;
        case ("november"): return 1 + NOVEMBER;
        case ("december"): return 1 + DECEMBER;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain why this version is more efficient than my original?

Comment: It's shorter (code efficiency) and it doesn't use temporary variables (space).

Comment: Three more things - 1) you can optimize for space or time (or some combination) and 2) you shouldn't optimize prematurely in the real-world, wait until you discover a bottleneck and 3) benchmark before and after.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
private static final String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

public static String numberToMonth(int iMonth) {
  return (iMonth < 12 && iMonth > 0) ? monthNames[iMonth - 1] : "None";
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I am understanding this correctly. You created a private instance array with the months inside, corresponding the index of each month to its respective number. You used `monthNames[iMonth-1]` because `i` would normally be `1` higher. When you type in `something.numberToMonth(1)` it would return the month in string format? And the obligatory conditions of no number greater than 12, and lower than 0. What is the `?` for?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the strings "1","2","3", ..., "12" to your monthToNumber method, that way you won't have to convert the user input to Integer using String.valueOf.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah in the number to month method you can just create a String array with the names of the months in chronological order and then just fetch the string at the index of the given input value minus 1